# How to use user input to create databases

Tags: database, python-2.7, python-3.x, sqlite

How do I get input from user to create databases in python? These data must stored in test.db file.

**Code**

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db');
print "Opened database successfully";


name=raw_input ("enter your name: ");
salary=raw_input("enter your salary: ");

conn.execute("INSERT INTO employee (NAME,SALARY) \
      VALUES ( r"+name+",r "+salary+")");

conn.commit()
```

Comment: Can you add the error you get here? also, `raw_input()` is `input()` in python3

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m1.py", line 13, in <module>
    VALUES ( r"+name+",r "+salary+")");
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "3432": syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concatenation is broken here, if salary is an integer you should do something like that:

```py
conn.execute("INSERT INTO employee (NAME,SALARY) \
    VALUES ( \"" + name + "\", " + str(salary) + ")");
```

Basically you need to escape some quotes around strings in your query.

Then to read your table you can do something like that:

```
for row in conn.execute('SELECT * FROM employee'):
    print row
```

Comment: you should have a grey tick you can click near its score (zero at the time)

Comment: You can do `DELETE FROM employee WHERE name = "myname"` for example.

Comment: name=raw_input ("enter your name: ");

conn.execute("DELETE FROM employee WHERE name =\""+ name+"\");

conn.commit()

Comment: mitesh@mitesh-Inspiron-N5010:~/Desktop$ python m3.py
  File "m3.py", line 12
    conn.execute("DELETE FROM employee WHERE name =\""+ name+"\");
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
mitesh@mitesh-Inspiron-N5010:~/Desktop$

Comment: Seems your line isn't complete, should be: `conn.execute("DELETE FROM employee WHERE name =\""+ name+"\");")`

Comment: i want like search the name .if the name is present in the databse then print yes other wise print does not exist. how to right this query?

Comment: import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('emp.db');
print "Opened database successfully";

na=raw_input("enter name which you want to show: ");

if(conn.execute("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE name=\""+ na+"\"")):
    print "yes"
else:
    print "no"



conn.commit()
print "Read data successfully";
conn.close()